# getClass out of String and using within generics

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

Because I'll get `String`'s from my websocket, I must convert the `String` to an actual type. Is it possible to do something like that?:

```
def createThing(cls: String) = {
  List[cls.getClass]()  // or create actors or something like that
}

createThing("Int") // should produce List[Int]

createThing("Double") // should produce List[Double]
```

Is it possible to achieve this? I'm new to with reflection, therefore I could not find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

No. The static type can't depend on runtime data in the way you want. E.g. should

```
createThing("Foo")
```

fail to compile if class `Foo` is not defined? However, you can do a lot of things without this. If you specify your problem better in a separate question, you may get answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this without mucking about with reflection. A minimalist class hierarchy can solve the problem quite effectively. Here is an example:

```
trait Message
case class StringList(strings: List[String]) extends Message
case class IntList(ints: List[Int]) extends Message

object Create {
  def createThing(cls: String): Option[Message] = cls match {
    case "strings" => Some(StringList(List[String]("a","b")))
    case "ints" => Some(IntList(List[Int](3,4,5)))
    case _ => None
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  val thing = Create.createThing("ints")
  thing match {
    case Some(a: StringList) => println(s"It was a StringList containing ${a.strings}")
    case Some(b: IntList) => println(s"It was an IntList containing ${b.ints}")
    case _ => println("Nothing we know about")
  }
}
```